# FontFamily not working after changing to a user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, user-controls, telerik

I have some code that used to work perfectly. However, trying to utilize the MVVM pattern I changed all of my "Views" from Windows to UserControls. My problem is that I was using an embedded font. Now, the font does not work and is reverted back to a default font. The fonts are still being built and saved in the same place and are present in the correct directories which is `builtDirectory/Fonts`. Here is the code that worked before.

```
<telerik:FontNumberPosition FontFamily="./Fonts/#DSEG7 Classic" FontSize="100" Background="Black" Foreground="LimeGreen" />
```

Also, I'm not sure if changing from a Window to a UserControl is the problem, as I have made quite a few changes since I noticed that the font wasn't working. That is about the only thing I can think of though that would cause the problem.

The font file's Build Action is set to Content and Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy if newer. I have verified that the font is indeed in the correct location after build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out my problem. It had nothing to do with the changing the View from a Window to a User Control. What had happened is that I moved it to a "View" folder that I created. Thus, when I used:

```
<telerik:FontNumberPosition FontFamily="./Fonts/#DSEG7 Classic" FontSize="100" Background="Black" Foreground="LimeGreen" />
```

It couldn't find the font.

To fix, I simply changed the above code to this:

```
<telerik:FontNumberPosition FontFamily="../Fonts/#DSEG7 Classic" FontSize="100" Background="Black" Foreground="LimeGreen" />
```